# Does some square of the first Chern class preserved by conifold transition?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology

Let $X$ be a smooth projective 3-fold or a symplectic 6-manifold.
Suppose $Y$ is a conifold transition on a single nullhomologous
Lagrangian sphere $S^{3}$ in $X$. Then there is a exact sequence $0\to
H^{2}(X)\rightarrow H^{2}(Y)\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\to0$ and
$c_{1}(X)=c_{1}(Y)$ under the inclusion. Is the square $c_{1}^{2}=0$
of the first Chern class preserved by the conifold transition? Why?

I suppose this is not always true. My reason is as follows: Let
$X_{0}=X\backslash S^{3}$. Then there is an isomorphism
$H^{4}(X)\rightarrow H^{4}(X_{0})$ and a exact sequence
$$0\to\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow H^{4}(Y)\rightarrow H^{4}(X_{0})\to0$$ 
So there may be some element $z\in\mathbb{Z}\subset H^{4}(Y)$ such
that $c_{1}^{2}(Y)=z$ but $c_{1}^{2}(X)=c_{1}^{2}(X_{0})=0$. Is that
right? Thank you.

Comment: See Corti-Smith: *Conifold transitions and Mori Theory*, Corollary 2.
http://intlpress.com/site/pub/pages/journals/items/mrl/content/vols/0012/0005/a013/index.html

Comment: @Polizzi I am just reading this paper. The proof just say that 'From the existence of the surgery as a local operation on Calabi-Yau’s, we
immediately get...'. But I can't understand. Can you explain this sentence a little  explicitly? Thank you very much.